# How in a numpy array we can select just rows that are multiples of for example 3?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I search for a `numpy` statement for doing this:

If
`a = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]`
and `b=3` then:

```
c = [rows that are multiples of b]=[11,14,17,20]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
a[::b]
```

Result:

```
array([11, 14, 17, 20])
```